# How do you get a UITextView to set cursor to between characters closest to drop point for drag and drop?

Tags: ios, uitextview

**EDIT:** Turns out I stumbled upon the answer, the UITextView has to be first responder first.

I'm trying to set the cursor position to the closest approximation for the release point of a drag and drop operation.  Here's what I've got so far, but the last step seems to do nothing.

```
UITextPosition *theTextPosition = [self.tweetTextView closestPositionToPoint:self.dragView.center];
UITextPosition *endPosition = [self.tweetTextView positionFromPosition:theTextPosition
                                                                offset:0];

UITextRange *textRange = [self.tweetTextView textRangeFromPosition:theTextPosition
                                                        toPosition:endPosition];

[self.tweetTextView setSelectedTextRange:textRange];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I stumbled upon the answer, the UITextView has to be first responder first.